# Lombok @Builder equality by initializing

Tags: java, lombok

Are there any differences between creating an object by the constructor or with a Lombok builder?

Basically, are these lines of code equivalent?

```
MyObject object = new MyObject();
```

```
MyObject object = MyObject.builder().build();
```

Comment: You could write a quick test to check if it is, no?

Comment: There is no difference. Lombok's generated builder class calls the constructor.

Comment: Yes, I can write a test. The result was surprising, because @Builder set null my variables, what have a default value.

Comment: You can delombok to have a look at the generated code. You will see that lombok uses @AllArgsConstructor to create the instance. Thats why all values are initialized with null if no values are given